How to clone a hard drive with multiple partitions
I'm brand new to Ubuntu so this might be obvious idk.
Is their a way to either clone an internal hard drive with multiple partitions to an external drive or save an image or create a file backup of an internal drive with multiple partitions to use on an external drive at a later date.
Hope this all makes sense.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Clonezilla

I prefer a full install & copy/rsync data or better restore from your normal backup to confirm backup is complete. If a clone you cannot reboot with both drives connected as duplicate UUIDs not allowed.

This question is similar to: How to clone entire hard-disk into new one?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
